# How to draw a line in autocad using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

> I want to draw a line in autocad using excelvba. 
>   I tried the following code but it give some run time error displaying "object doesn't support this property or method" at the 2nd last line.
>   Please help me to fix this.

```
Dim point1(1 To 3) As Double
Dim point2(1 To 3) As Double
Dim lineobj As Object
Dim myapp As Object
Dim AcadDwg As AcadDocument

Sub access_autocad()
On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
Set myapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application")

ERRORHANDLER:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
    Set myapp = CreateObject("autocad.application")
    End If
    myapp.Visible = True
Set AcadDwg = myapp.ActiveDocument
point1(1) = 0: point1(2) = 0
point2(1) = 1: point2(2) = 1
Set lineobj = AcadDwg.AddLine(point1, point2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make one change.  On the next to last line, change:

```
   Set lineobj = AcadDwg.AddLine(point1, point2)
```

To:

```
   Set lineobj = AcadDwg.ModelSpace.AddLine(point1, point2)
```

Comment: It works. But i have another problem. It works fine when i open autocad at first and run this code. But it can't automatically opens autocad when i run it without opening autocad. It take long time and cannot open at the end. I would very much appreciate it if you could help me here.

Comment: The good news is that your code works as expected on my machine.  The bad news is I don't know exactly why it doesn't work on your machine.  I have seen this on occasion, though.